# Magento 2, Applied discount amount not display on checkout and order item table

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, discount, simple-product, virtual-products

I have created a **Catalog Price Rule** for 10% discount like the below image [image]

It applied product price, but its **not showing on checkout** details and also the discounted amount details are not saved in the **"tbl_sales_order_item"** table. so I cannot get it in the invoice details. How can I get the discounted amount and percentage from the order tables

Comment: you applied this discount on catalog having id 7 do you apply it on the requested category id products?

Comment: can you please double verify to cart product belongs to category id is 7